# awk: escape $ in pattern matching

Tags: awk

**My Scenario:**
I am writing a bash script in which, I am trying to match pattern using following command.

```
awk '/'$messageID'/' /file/path/fileName
```

where $messageID is a bash variable.

**I am facing following problem:**
As long as `$messageID` contains string without any special characters it works fine but if variable contains any special character like `$` command do not gives proper output.

**Expected result:**
Even if variable `$messageID` contains special character, output should be proper.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you pass the variable to awk?

```
awk -v m="$match" '$0 ~ m' file
```

This way, you do not have to worry about any character.

#### Test

```
$ match="te$t"

$ cat a
hello this is
a te$t line
with other te$t info

$ awk -v m="$match" '$0 ~ m' a
a te$t line
with other te$t info
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be an idea to enclose `$match` in double quotes?

Comment: +1 answer is short and clear! Maybe it is not relevant to OP's requirement: in awk regexp constants and dynamic regexps do have little difference. One should be ware of.